# Storing/Getting Asynchronous Storage Values inside componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to save the name that a user enters into a TextInput such that every proceeding time a user opens the app their name will still be saved.

I am trying to use react-native's Asynchronous storage to get the name inside the componentDidMount() function. I believe that the value is not being set inside the onSubmit() method when it is being called. I tried removing the await keyword in the async function. I read other the documentation and can't find where I am going wrong.

```
onSubmit = () => {
   var that = this
   var data = this.state.textValue;
   nameDict['name'] = data;
   _setData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.setItem('name',data)
      that.setState({textValue:'',name:data})
    } catch (error) {
      that.setState({textValue:'',name:'error'})
    }
  } 
 }

componentDidMount(){
  var that = this;
  var name = ''

this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position)=>{
  _retrieveData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('name')
      name = value

    } catch (error) {
        // Error retrieving data
    }
  } 
}
```

The name variable in ComponentDidMount() is always an empty string, so either it has not been changed at all or the getItem() function is not resolving and returning the name. However, I am not sure which of the two it could be. Am I using the Async functions incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set set **componentDidMount** to **async** also

example using your data:

```
async componentDidMount(){

var that = this;
  var name = ''

this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position)=>{
  _retrieveData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.getItem('name').then((value)=>name=value);
    } catch (error) {
        // Error retrieving data
    }
  } 
}
```

I recommend making **name** global if you want to actually use the value.

next, this might be personal but i recommend to **JSON.stringify()** the values when storing data and **JSON.parse()** when retrieving the data

example when retrieving **stringify** data

```
async componentDidMount(){

var that = this;
  var name = ''

this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position)=>{
  _retrieveData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.getItem('name').then((value)=>name=JSON.parse(value));
    } catch (error) {
        // Error retrieving data
    }
  } 
}
```

if this was helpful please set as the answer if not please leave a comment.

Comment: I followed your steps but I still get name as an empty string. Is something wrong with AsyncStorage itself? I have read that AsyncStorage has a multitude of issues.

Comment: are you testing on emulator or real device? did  you make any personal modifications?

Comment: Testing on an emulator, and I did not make any personal modifications

Comment: Okay I used expo to test my app on a real device and got the following error: "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection. TypeError: error is not a function".

Comment: normally get the error when you are making request to an api or get info from some outside source. you have to `.catch((err)=>dosomething())` after a request has be rejected, **dosomething()** being what you want to do if the request fails. sorry for late replies i go to university